# NameError: name 'JSONResponseMixin' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-3.0

I am getting this error but I don't get it why? I am following the Django documents and part of the code which get error is from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/ (the last code in the link)

The error:

```
/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    class ProgramListView(ListView, JSONResponseMixin, SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin):
NameError: name 'JSONResponseMixin' is not defined
```

My Code in views.py:

```
from programs.models import Program
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin
from django.views.generic.detail import BaseDetailView




class ProgramListView(ListView, JSONResponseMixin, SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin):
    
    model = Program
    template_name = 'programs/program_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'programs'
    paginate_by = 6
    paginate_orphans = 3

    def get_queryset(self):

        url_parameter = self.request.GET.get('q')

        # if self.request.method == 'GET' and self.request.is_ajax():
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            queryset = Program.objects.filter(degree = url_parameter)
            return queryset

        if self.request.method == 'GET' and url_parameter is None:
            queryset = Program.objects.all()
            return queryset


    def render_to_response(self, context, url_parameter='BSc'):
        # Look for a 'format=json' GET argument
        # if self.request.GET.get('format') == 'json':
        # if self.request.is_ajax():
        if url_parameter=='BSc':
            return self.render_to_json_response(context)
        else:
            return super().render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: You must define the JsonResponseMixing class [Resource](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not importing JSONResponseMixin. Matter of fact Django has no such mixin, it's only an example.

If you really want to add it, add this code above your `class ProgramListView`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class JSONResponseMixin:
    """
    A mixin that can be used to render a JSON response.
    """
    def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        """
        Returns a JSON response, transforming 'context' to make the payload.
        """
        return JsonResponse(
            self.get_data(context),
            **response_kwargs
        )

    def get_data(self, context):
        """
        Returns an object that will be serialized as JSON by json.dumps().
        """
        # Note: This is *EXTREMELY* naive; in reality, you'll need
        # to do much more complex handling to ensure that arbitrary
        # objects -- such as Django model instances or querysets
        # -- can be serialized as JSON.
        return context
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#jsonresponsemixin-example

Alternatively, you can just return a JSON response directly like this:

```
if url_parameter=='BSc':
            return JsonResponse(context)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Do you know why I get 'Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable' error when the code works?

Comment: @UlviDamirli Because a queryset is a database iterator, not a simple array that can be serialized. You need to use a serializer in the middle.